# Why doesn't setting NodeJS module cache to false get NodeJS to reload module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, node-modules

I have 2 files, one named one.js and other name first.js.
**one.js**

```
var first = require("./first.js")
require.cache[first.module.id].loaded=false
require("./first.js")
```

**first.js**

```
console.log("First is running");
module.exports={module}
```

It's output is:

```
First is running
```

and not

```
First is running
First is running
```

as I expected. Why is it that even though I set the loaded property of the first.js module to false, it is still not being reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the cached module from the `require.cache` object to force node to load the module again. Node won't execute the module as long as it is in the `require.cache`.

One way to delete the module from the cache is shown below:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve("./first.js")];
```

---

**Side Tip:** You could export a function from a module and just call that function again and again to have a similar result of loading the module everytime it is required.