# Require independent instances of module inside class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, requirejs, vscode-extensions

I am a beginner in nodejs. I am developing a vscode extension based on this [guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md). I defined a class that requires an external js module, e.g. :

`thepanel.ts`:

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";
var externalLibrary = require("@x/y");  

export class myPanel {
   public static currentPanel: myPanel| undefined;
   private constructor( panel: vscode.webviewPanel, extensionUri: vscode.Uri, someIdentifier:string){
          //.. initialization of MyPanel.. 
          externalLibrary.someInitializationMethod(someIdentifier);  
         //^ This makes an important setup within externalLibrary based on `someIdentifier`. 
   }

    public static render (extensionUri: vscode.Uri, someIdentifier: string, .. other parameters ..){
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel("open-panel", "Panel", .. other parameters .. ){
           // .. stuff..
           myPanel.currentPanel = new myPanel(panel, extensionUri, someIdentifier); 
       }
    }

   //.. other stuff .. , 
   // including a method to update the information when I press a refresh button in the webview..

}
```

In `extension.ts`, I registered a command to open a new panel:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { myPanel } from "./panels/thepanel.ts";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext){
 const newPanelCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand("myextension.newPanel", () => {
 
 // ... Some code to prompt user for `someIdentifier` or set a default value .. 

 myPanel.render(context.extensionUri, someIdentifier, .. other parameters .. );
}
}
```

Upon testing the extension, I:

1. Open a new panel with `someIdentifier1`. It works and shows the information I expect to see given `someIdentifier1`. I press a button that updates the information displayed on the webview, and I get the expected updated information, I can do this as many times as I want and get the expected result.
2. Open a new panel with `someIdentifier2`. It works and shows the information I expect to see given `someIdentifier2`. I press a button that updates the information displayed on the webview, and I get the expected updated information, I can do this as many times as I want and get the expected result.
3. I go back to the first panel and press the button that updates the information displayed on the webview, but instead of getting the updated information I expect given `someIdentifier1`, I instead get the updated information associated to `someIdentifier2`.

Why?

I added the following line

```js
console.log(externalLibrary.ready_);
```

to the `constructor` function in `myPanel` just before calling `externalLibrary.someInitializationMethod(someIdentifier)`. The `.ready_` parameter should be `"not_ready"` prior to calling `someInitializationMethod`. I re-did steps 1-3, and I noticed that in step 2, `.ready_` parameter was `"ready"`, instead of `"not_ready"`. This means that `externalLibrary` in the second panel is *not independent* from `externalLibrary` in the first panel.

How can I achieve having `externalLibrary` being completely independent for each panel?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125459/is-a-node-js-module-instance-created-for-each-require) and in it I found the explanation from the official docs that mentions that [modules are cached after the first time they are loaded](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). In this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72240882/why-doesnt-setting-nodejs-module-cache-to-false-get-nodejs-to-reload-module) I found that one solution is to delete the cache by doing:

```js
delete require.cache[require.resolve("library")];
```

What I am not sure is where should I add this?

### Attempted solution

I already tried to modify `thepanel.ts` as follows:

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";  

export class myPanel {
   public static currentPanel: myPanel| undefined;
   private _externalLibrary: any;

   private constructor( panel: vscode.webviewPanel, extensionUri: vscode.Uri, someIdentifier:string){
          //.. initialization of MyPanel.. 

          delete require.cache[require.resolve("@x/y")];
          this._externalLibrary = require("@x/y");


          externalLibrary.someInitializationMethod(someIdentifier);  
         //^ This makes an important setup within externalLibrary based on `someIdentifier`. 
   }

    public static render (extensionUri: vscode.Uri, someIdentifier: string, .. other parameters ..){
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel("open-panel", "Panel", .. other parameters .. ){
           // .. stuff..
           myPanel.currentPanel = new myPanel(panel, extensionUri, someIdentifier); 
       }
    }

   //.. other stuff .. , 
   // including a method to update the information when I press a refresh button in the webview..  And importantly, in this update I make use of `externalLibrary` by using this._externalLibrary.nameOfTheMethod.. 

}
```

.. but I still got the same unexpected behavior.

#### What is the correct way to achieving independence for each instance of `externalLibrary`?

Again, I am a beginner with `nodejs` and would like to learn the best practices, so please be detailed in the explanation.

Comment: It's not possible by design. Modules are singletons. A module is an instance. You cannot instance an instance. If you need something that can be instanced multiple times you need a class. If the library is something you've written you need to change the object into a class. If not you need to find another library to use. If there are none you can perhaps find the github page of that library and fork it and modify it to your needs.

Comment: .. or a closure. You need either a class or a closure. Both are instanceable.